# Multiplying Absolute Values

Tags: proof-verification

How do I multiply a non-absolute value with an absolute value? For example: |x-1| to be multiplied with x^2? I got an answer of x^2|x-1| but I'm pretty sure it's wrong.

Thank you!

Comment: Note that $|x-1|$ is always positive and so is $x^2$? What will then happen?

Comment: Do I simply distribute x^2 to (x-1)?

Comment: How would I answer this problem though: |x-1| + x^2? I split it up into x-1 = x^2 and x-1 = x^2. Not sure if this is right, though.

Comment: divide your problem into two cases, one for $(x-1)\geq0$ and one for $(x-1)<0$

Answer (score 1):

Just $$x^2|x-1|.$$ Alternate forms are: $$|x^3-x^2| = \sqrt{(x^3-x^2)^2} = x^2 \sqrt{(x-1)^2}.$$

Answer (score 0):

If you want to take off the modulus, follow this procedure:

We know $(x-1)\geq 0$ for $x\geq1$ and less than zero for $x<1$. Then, we will have: $$x^2|x-1| = \begin{cases} x^2(x-1) &\mbox{if }x\geq 1\\x^2(1-x)&\mbox{if }x<1\end{cases}$$

Can you do likewise for the case of addition as well?